# Kendo-Grid Truncate string with no white-space

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo-Grid for filtering, everything is working fine except for a problem on my cell if there is no white space.
As displayed in the image:

[image]

the string is "https://www.linkedi/Testing" but it's displayed only until "Test".

This problem does not appear for string with white spaces like:

[image]

I'm newbie in client-side programming, thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior should be like this:

[image: overflow]

Im not sure why in your case its not like this, maybe older version of kendo.

To achieve the above behavior add css:

```
/*Overides kendo default*/
.k-grid td {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Example: [ellipsis](https://dojo.telerik.com/IJIVAduS)

To achieve text in new line add css:

```
/*Overides kendo default*/
.k-grid td {
      word-break: break-all;
}
```

Example: [brake-all](https://dojo.telerik.com/IJUmUYeB)

Comment: Np, if the answer resolved your problem please accept it as the correct one.